# Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I'm getting the following error *"javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0"* when I try to connect to a remote mysql server. Others running the same code do not get this error, any idea what I need to fix/change?

If it helps I'm using IntelliJ and java 1.8.

Comment: seems like you are having issues with certificates.

Comment: Can you paste your code snippet. This error usually comes when you use different SSL protocols to communicate with each other.